# Activate dropout layers during inference in R

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I have a Keras model in R, and am looking to perform Monte Carlo dropout during inference. I know there are methods in Python by turning `training = TRUE`, but I can't find a similar functionality in R.

Take an example Keras model:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
    layer_dense(10, activation = "relu") %>%
    layer_dropout(0.2)
```

(not my model, mine is unnecessarily complex for stackoverflow)

In this case, the dropout will only work during training, but be completely ignored when predictions are made. I want the dropout to work during prediction, so each prediction is different.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `training = TRUE` in `keras` R like this:

```r
library(keras)
dropout_1 <- layer_dropout(rate = 0.2) 

model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_dense(10, activation = "relu") %>%
  dropout_1(training = TRUE)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank, I maybe should have thought through it a bit more. The model is a functional API model, and the layers are provided as a list of layers. The model graph is complex and is build using a function where a list of hidden layers is supplied - following your solution gets the error:
ValueError: The first argument to `Layer.call` must always be passed.

Comment: Hi @jackahall, you can do this for each layer.